Is there any way to read from a file with non-blocking mode?
I want to read from /dev/kmsg to realize a dmesg like function in Go.
After reading all data from this device, the os.File.Read() is not returned. The code from os.File.FD.Read() shows if EAGAIN is returned from syscall and fd.pd is pollable then Read() would keep trying to read again:
// Read implements io.Reader.
func (fd *FD) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    if err := fd.readLock(); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    defer fd.readUnlock()
    if len(p) == 0 {
        // If the caller wanted a zero byte read, return immediately
        // without trying (but after acquiring the readLock).
        // Otherwise syscall.Read returns 0, nil which looks like
        // io.EOF.
        // TODO(bradfitz): make it wait for readability? (Issue 15735)
        return 0, nil
    }
    if err := fd.pd.prepareRead(fd.isFile); err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    if fd.IsStream && len(p) > maxRW {
        p = p[:maxRW]
    }
    for {
        n, err := ignoringEINTRIO(syscall.Read, fd.Sysfd, p)
        if err != nil {
            n = 0
            if err == syscall.EAGAIN && fd.pd.pollable() {
                if err = fd.pd.waitRead(fd.isFile); err == nil {
                    continue
                }
            }
        }
        err = fd.eofError(n, err)
        return n, err
    }
}

I assume the implement of this function means if this pd is pollable (which means the fd is set non-blocking) and EAGAIN returned, function will keep trying to read again. In this case it not fit my occasion. Meanwhile if this fd is blocking it won't fit my occasion either.
Is there any way to finish reading if EAGAIN returned? If some wrappers or packages can do this or I have to realize this myself?

You can do something like this but the real question is: what is the real problem? Go appears to handle blocking of /dev/kmsg as documented so you basically can just loop over reads from it (probably using bufio.Scanner). So what real problem are you having? I'm asking because for now it smells like an XY Problem to me.

You can look here: https://medium.com/@cpuguy83/non-blocking-i-o-in-go-bc4651e3ac8d
They are using syscall.Open with O_NONBLOCK parameter

@kostix I have tried to read with os.File.Read(), after the last message is read the read syscall returned EAGAIN and os.File.Read() is waiting for new data. And I tried bufio.Scanner after getting your answer while got the same result.
You mentioned the /dev/kmsg but you didn't realize what it said

"Every read() will receive the next available record. If no more records are available read() will block, or if O_NONBLOCK is used -EAGAIN returned."


@kostix You didn't realize the question is GO package handled EAGAIN internally and the invoker has no chance to handle this scenario.

If the file is pollable, then you can use SetReadDeadline to return if no new data appears before that deadline.

«GO package handled EAGAIN internally»–I still fail to see the problem; can you elaborate? Suppose, I called Read on the opened file, it had unread messages and returned (their bytes). Suppose the next call got blocked; it does not matter which mechanism exactly had made it block, I mean, the reading goroutine just got blocked in the Read call. The call will unblock as soon as there is new data for it to read, so it will be able to proceed. So, where is the problem here, or what exactly I fail to see? You appear to do not want Read to block, but what's the problem with it? It's a feature :-)

…To better explain my point: in Go, all calls which may ever block are supposed to block their calling goroutines. This is a feature allowing you to write "serial"/"sequential" code w/o callback hell or sweeping it under the rug using "promises" and "futures". Basically, you just have a dedicated goroutine read (in a loop) and process the data when another piece of it gets ready. The processing goroutine just sleeps in between these "data is ready" moments. If you need to deliver these pieces of data elsewhere, use a channel or some other form of communication between goroutines.

@kostix I mean the syscall returned EAGAIN but the wrapper(e.g. os.File.Read()) handled internally which acts like os.File.Read() is always working in a blocking mode even the file is opened in non-blocking mode. I just want a simple or single goroutine to read all data from /dev/kmesg and when there's no data just finish my work. So I don't want the read action get 'blocked' in any ways. I just want to get the native EAGAIN from syscall and finish my job and don't want to use channel or something like that.

@kostix BTW I got a solution from @T0maas which works for me by operating the native fd with os.File.SyscallConn and syscall.RawConn.Read.

@Martzki, I got it now, thanks. Still, can you share a use case for this approach? I mean, your approach looks like only suitable for timer-controlled polling, or for a case when you somehow know for sure there gonna be a message in the kernel buffer so your single calls is guaranteed to succeed.

@kostix In my case I just try to read all data from /dev/kmsg once and I don't care about new messages, so I need 'break' the reading loop and finish reading when there's no more data at a certain time. Sounds like execute dmesg in shell normally.
